# Selenium WebDriver DragAndDrop for IE9

Tags: internet-explorer, drag-and-drop, webdriver

I am looking for a workaround to drag and drop a div on another in IE.

The native call

(new Actions(TestSetup.webDriver)).dragAndDrop(sourceElement, destinationElement).perform();

Works fine for Chrome and Firefox, but fails in IE.

Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: Haha, I believe that's for the browser right? But business still wants it to be done on IE.

Comment: I apologize, I did thumb it up and added a comment, but I did not know until now how to accept the answer. I have now accepted the previous answer. But I do appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this was solved or not, but you will probably need to execute the individual mouse clicks and move actions without the drag and drop from Selenium.  In theory it should be the same thing, but there might be a case where when you have one element held and selenium is not finding the other element while one is in focus and being dragged.

I would recommend getting both elements and saving the locations and then clickandhold one element and then move it to the location of the other element and then release the mouse at that location.  This should bypass any browser specific issues and focus just on the mouse and the window by pixel.

If that still doesn't work then please provide more specific details to the selenium error and the web page.

Answer (score 1):

When initializing your IE driver, set the `RequireWindowFocus` option to true.

This is how it's done in C#:

```
var ieOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions
{
    RequireWindowFocus = true
}
var driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieOptions);
```

If using a remote Selenium server:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.InternetExplorer();
capabilities.SetCapability("requireWindowFocus", true);
var driver = new RemoteWebDriver(Constants.RemoteSeleniumServer, capabilities);
```

According to the docs:

> Introduced the "requireWindowFocus" capability into the IE driver. When used in conjunction with the "nativeEvents" capability, the driver will attempt to bring the current IE window to the foreground before executing a mouse or keyboard event.
>
> Also, when the requireWindowFocus capability is set to true, advanced user interactions will now use the Windows SendInput() API to execute the interactions. To enable this behavior, set the value of the
> requiresWindowFocus capability to "true" when creating an instance of the IE driver. The default for this new capability is "false". This functionality is currently considered extremely experimental; use at your own risk.